# How to use Cache Memory of device in Android application?

Tags: android, performance, caching

In an android application,I have a button;When a user clicks the button, app hits external PHP server and downloads json data and display it in a listview.

Now suppose after a short moment of time user again clicks that button.App will again fetch json data using HttpURLConnection.My question is that can we increase the speed of fetching data from json by using cache memory of the device(like browsers do) or HttpURLConnection library internally implements it?

Comment: "increase the speed of fetching data from json by using cache" if your json is different from the previous one you have to download it again, but if they are not different you can cache it and use it from your memory but you must set expiration period. if you want to give a better UX and your json is different you can download next one after receiving the current request.

Comment: @ mmlooloo - yes my json is same but I dont want to use app memory.Is there not a possiblity to use cache memory of the device like browsers cache recently visited URLs? Does HttpURLConnection which opens the connection to external URL have any sort of implementation for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know a Library that can achieve what you need its called [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice), i really recommend you to check it, it makes the asynchronous calls in a BackService, then update your UI's as needed, as you want it has a Cache implemented that expires when you need it, also it has their own JSON decoders, please check it out. If you need more info check the wiki on the page or comment here. Good Luck.